# different DelegatingFilterProxy and FilterToBeanProxy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can anyone clearly explain to me the differences between these two classes defined in web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FilterToBeanProxy (F2BP) was an Acegi Security class tht had a similar use as Springs DelegatingFilterProxy (DFP).  As far as I can tell there is no need to ever use F2BP anymore, now that Acegi Security is part of Spring you can use Spring's DFP to the same effect.

See the javadocs for confirmation : 
[FilterToBeanProxy Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/util/FilterToBeanProxy.html)